# My Batis delete query return type not consistent

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis

I am using spring-mybatis for a Delete query

this is how my calls look like

```
if(mapper.deleteSomething(id))
{

.....
}
```

And in my mapper i have

```
<delete id = "deleteSomething">
delete from table where id = #{id}
</delete>
```

However I noticed that return type is not always true in case of successful deletion. Sometimes it returns true and sometimes false, But the records are always deleted in db.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Delete should return integer and Integer value will be number of rows deleted. Hence change your mapper interface return type to integer

Comment: I changed the return type to int, but still I get the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Here is changes you need to make.

1. Change the mapper interface method

   ```
    public interface yourinterface{
      public int deleteSomething(<data type> id)
    }
   ```

   I see in your mapper file there is no parameter type mentioned for input, its better to add
2. Change if condition

   ```
    int count =mapper.deleteSomething(id);
    if(count>0){
      System.out.println("Deleted "+ count +"records");
    }else{
      System.out.println("Delete failed");
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi, I am doing exactly the same. However During consecutive executions sometimes count is coming 0, but it is getting deleted from the db.

Comment: Your using any transaction?........ what is the log says. which db are you using?

Comment: hi,Yes I am using transaction and I am using mysql.

Comment: Are you using ExecutorType as batch? If yes, try using ExecutorType.SIMPLE when calling openSession.